# How can I put GPIO.HIGH in a variable

Tags: gpio, python

I have a python program what control relay board via GPIO.
When I set a GPIO port LOW the relay closes and HIGH opens the relay
As example. I use this line to close the relay and open it again after 10 seconds

```
GPIO = webiopi.GPIO

GPIO.digitalWrite(18, GPIO.LOW)
time.sleep(10)
GPIO.digitalWrite(18, GPIO.HIGH)
```

Now I've bought a new relay board, which works to opposite. On a GPIO.LOW it opens and a GPIO.HIGH the relais close

I thought to use this code, which is not working

```
GPH=GPIO.LOW
GPL=GPIO.HIGH
GPIO.digitalWrite(18, GPH)
time.sleep(10)
GPIO.digitalWrite(18, GPL)
```

> GPH=GPIO.LOW   NameError: name 'GPIO' is not defined

My question is: what is the proper way to put GPIO.HIGH and GPIO.LOW in a variable? so I can easy switch those.

Comment: what do you mean "it's not working"? And what's the point of the sleep line, you are not changing the state of the relay.

Comment: GPH=GPIO.HIGH  gives this error : NameError: name 'GPIO' is not defined  (I've correct this in the question now)

Comment: I assume you remembered the import RPi.GPIO as GPIO line?

Comment: yes, using webiopi      ->   GPIO = webiopi.GPIO

Comment: It's not working because GPIO does not exist.  You need to have GPIO=webopi.GPIO prior to using GPH=GPIO.LOW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GPIO.HIGH  is a True or 1

GPIO.LOW is False or 0

So to solve this issue the following changes must be made:

```
GPH=False
GPL=True
GPIO.digitalWrite(18, GPH)
time.sleep(10)
GPIO.digitalWrite(18, GPL)
```